# Тестинг на PhpUnit

Tags: юнит-тесты, phpunit

Есть `API`, который является `get` запросом. Но `API` работает не правильно, так как при вставление место `get` `post`, он опять правильно работает.

Как в `PhpUnit` можно проверить. Если запрос `get`, но правильно работает и с `post` то дать `false`.

Comment: Покажите ваш тест. Что значит дать false? используйте обычный `if`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам достаточно сделать проверку:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    return false;
}
```